# Unable to get relevant tweet replies to make a thread using twitter api in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm trying to compile threads from twitter but there isn't a way to compile tweets directly using the twitter API.

Hence using the node library [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit), I have written the following code to compile threads.

```js
var Twit = require('twit');

var twitter = new Twit({
  consumer_key: "mykey",
  consumer_secret: "mysecret",
  access_token: "token",
  access_token_secret: "secret",
});

const tweetId = '1126756595935862787';
twitter.get('statuses/show/:id', {id: tweetId}, (err, res, mess) => {
  if(err) return console.log('Error: ', err);
  console.log('Tweet: ', res.text);
  console.log('=====replies=====');
  parseTimelineforReplies(tweetId);
})


async function parseTimelineforReplies(id) {
  twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: 'paraschopra', since_id: id, exclude_replies: false, count: 5000, include_rts: true}, (err, tweets, res) => {
    if(err) return Promise.reject('Error getting users timeline', err);
    console.log('Length', tweets.length);
    for(let t of tweets) {
      if(t.in_reply_to_status_id_str === id) {
        console.log(t.text);
        console.log('----');
        parseTimelineforReplies(t.id_str);
      }

    }
    return Promise.resolve(tweets);
  });
}
```

In the code above I am first getting a specific tweet using its ID and then I'm trying to match that ID in the `user_timeline` as a reply recursively to fetch all the replies and form a thread.

This works fine for recent tweets, but the `tweetId` I have used in the example above is of this [tweet](https://twitter.com/paraschopra/status/1126756595935862787), which evidently is a thread and has replies.

But this is the output I'm getting:

```
Tweet:  Some thoughts on how to rise up in the economic ladder.

(A thread) //From first tweet
=====replies=====
Length 200
//None of the replies are matching
```

I can't understand what is going wrong, my hypothesis is that the API is fetching the most recent tweets after this tweet that's why it's missing the thread, because this tweet was made on 10th May 2019.

Help would be very much appreciated.